# Multiple select input must be selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two select input, the two must be selected before the #GO button shows.

( dbname,user) <--- the two select input, choose what database and choose a user to access the database.

The problem with this query is that after choosing one of the two the #GO button will show. The two must be selected before the #GO shows, if not then the #GO button hides.

the script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("select").on('change',function() {


    var x = $('select[name=name]').val();
    var y = $('select[name=dbname]').val();

    if (x == 0  && y == 0) {
       $("#GO").hide();
    } else if (x == 1  && y == 0) {
        $("#GO").hide();
    } else if (y==0 && x==1) {
        $("#GO").hide();
    }else{
       $("#GO").show();
    }
});
```

this the php file:

```
        <?php   echo "<select name='name' id='name'>";
                $res = $conn->query("SELECT user FROM mysql.user");
                    echo    '<option value="0">Select User</option>';
                    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['user'] . '">' . $row['user'] . '</option>'; }
                            echo '</select>';
                echo "<br/>"; 

        ?>

        <br>

        <?php   echo "<select name='dbname' id='dbname'>";
                $res = $conn->query("show databases");
                    echo    '<option value="0">Select Database</option>';
                    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['Database'] . '">' . $row['Database'] . '</option>'; }
                            echo '</select>';
                echo "<br/>"; 

        ?><br>


                <input type="submit" name="GO" value="GO" id="GO" class="GO">
```

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing? (Or) What would like to achieve?

Comment: Try `if (x == 0  || y == 0) {` instead of `if (x == 0  && y == 0) {`... OR instead of AND.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks, i just realized that the operational condition i was using was the AND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is to use "||" which means "OR", instead of "&&" which means "AND".

In this case, if any of them are 0, it will be hidden.

```
if (x == 0  || y == 0) {
  $("#GO").hide();
}else{
  $("#GO").show();
}
```

You can also do it like this:

```
//It checks whether both x and y are Not 0, if true, shows "#GO", else, stays hidden.

if (x != 0  && y != 0) {
  $("#GO").show();
}else{
  $("#GO").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i just realized that the operational condition i was using was the AND.

Answer (score 0):

Here `if (x == 0  && y == 0)`,the  condition says hide the #GO button if and only if both are not selected. But you should be checking if one of them is not selected then hide the button. So the condition must be `if (x == 0  || y == 0)` which means either on of them is not selected.

Again,

```
else if (x == 1  && y == 0) {
    $("#GO").hide();
} else if (y==0 && x==1) {
    $("#GO").hide();
```

There's no difference between these two conditions above.

Here's what you want

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").on('change',function() {
        var x = $('select[name=name]').val();
        var y = $('select[name=dbname]').val();

        if (x == 0  ||y == 0) {
           $("#GO").hide();
        }else{
           $("#GO").show();
        }
    });
});
```

This will be enough to achieve what you want to do

Comment: Thanks, i just realized that the operational condition i was using was the AND.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var GO = $('#GO');
  var dbname = $('#dbname');
  var name = $('#name');

  GO.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //initially disabled

  function EnableDisableGo() {

    if (verifySelect()) {
        GO.attr('disabled', '');
    } else {
        GO.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }

  function verifySelect() {
    if (dbname.val() != '' && name.val() != '') { //if both selected
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
  }

 dbname.change(EnableDisableGo);

 name.change(EnableDisableGo);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to do this, with a filter and toggle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").on('change',function() {
        $('#GO').toggle(
            $('#name, #dbname').filter(function() {
                return this.value === $('option',this).first().val();
            }).length === 0
        );
    }).trigger('change')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='name' id='name'>";
    <option value="0">Select User</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select name='dbname' id='dbname'>
    <option value="0">Select Database</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="GO" value="GO" id="GO" class="GO">
```